# What does 1 (mod N) mean?

Tags: javascript, modulo

I am trying to implement a simple algorithm in JavaScript. Wherever I look, it calls for the code to work out `1 (mod N)`. As far as I can tell, 1 modulo anything (or `1%N`) is 1.

What am I missing? Is it always 1, and if so, why not just use 1?

Comment: "1 modulo anything (or 1%N) is 1" - unless N is 1, in which case the result is zero.

Comment: The key thing to understand is that in mathematical notation, `(mod n)` applies to *both* sides of an expression, even
though it's usually only written on the right-hand side (see
[Confused about modular notations](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78367/confused-about-modular-notations)).
So, going off @Blender's answer, the expression `a ≡ 1 (mod N)` should be read as "`a ≡ 1` when the system is
taken `modulo N`", or `a % N == 1 % N` (or just `a % N == 1`, since `1 % N` always equals 1).

Comment: “(mod n) applies to both sides of an expression, even though it's usually only written on the right-hand side” - thank you, I finally understand the formulas I’m staring at.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The algorithm probably says something like:

```
x ≡ 1 (mod N)  # x is congruent to 1 (modulo N)
```

The `(mod N)` and the triple equals sign denote that you're working with modular arithmetic, not normal arithmetic. Think of it like the hands of a clock. In modular arithmetic, `x ≡ 1` means that `x` and `1` belong to the same [residue class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence_classes). If you have a clock with `N` hour divisions, turning the hand `1` time or `x` times will bring the hand to the same end position.

For your specific case, `x ≡ 1 (mod N)` can be represented as `x % N === 1` in JavaScript *if `x` is never negative*. Otherwise, your equality will not hold even though it should: for example, `-1 ≡ 1 (mod 2)` but `(-1) % 2 === -1`, which isn't equal to `1` even though they're "equal" in the modular arithmetic sense.

If you expect `x` to be negative, you can just rearrange the congruence relation:

```
       x ≡ 1 (mod N)
⇒  x - 1 ≡ 0 (mod N)
```

`x - 1` being congruent to `0` means that it's divisible by `N` itself, so you can use the modulo operator safely:

```
if ((x - 1) % N === 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: To clarify: `x ≡ 1 (mod N)` is *really* `x % N == 1 % N`, which simplifies to `x % N == 1` because `1 % N == 1` (assuming `N` is not 1).

Answer (score 1):

How the modulo (%) operator works is defined in [ECMA-262 §11.5.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.5.3). There are a few quirks, the ECMAScript modulo operator accepts floats as well as integers:

For integers:

```
1 % -Infinity returns 1
...
1 % -2 returns 1
1 % -1 returns 0
1 %  0 returns NaN
1 %  1 returns 0
1 %  2 returns 1
...
1 % Infinity returns 1
```

For floats,

```
1 % -1.1 returns 1
1 %  0.1 returns 0.09999999999999995
1 %  0.6 returns 0.4
1 %  0.5 returns 0
1 %  0.4 returns 0.19999999999999996
1 %  0.9 returns 0.09999999999999998
1 %  1.1 returns 1
```

So without the context of how the modulo operator is being applied, it's very difficult to determine why it's being used. Best of all would be documentation of the code, but I suppose that's not available.

One use is, where an integer is expected, to evaluate 0 and 1 as false and everything else as true, so:

```
if (1 % n) {
  // do this if n is something other than 0 or 1
}
```